# In echo sumbit button not redirecting in php

Tags: php

echo html code  onclick of button redirection.

I have tried  by using button and input tags both.

```
while($_row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$_row['id']."\">" . $_row['id'] ."&nbsp;".$_row['name'].'&nbsp;'.$_row['contact'].'';
    echo"<input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick='document.location.href='/project1/delete.php''";
    echo"?id=".$_row['id'];
    echo" />";
    echo"<input type='button' value='EDIT' onclick='document.location.href='/project1/edit.php''";
    echo"?id=".$_row['id'];
    echo" /><br>";
    $id=$_row['id'];
 }
```

Comment: and your actual question is?

Comment: i have to use input box to get data from id and delete from respective id in database.

Comment: That's still not a question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- **In your code 'Unexpected end of input' issue is there with onclick.**

2- you can use [concatenating](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) assignment operator ('.='), which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side. and last display the output.

```
<?php
while($_row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $id = $_row['id'];
    $name = $_row['name'];
    $contact = $_row['contact'];

    $output ='';
    $output.="<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$id."\">" . $id ."&nbsp;".$name.'&nbsp;'.$contact;
    $output.="<input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick=\"document.location.href='/project1/delete.php?id=$id'\"/>";
    $output.="<input type='button' value='EDIT' onclick=\"document.location.href='/project1/edit.php?id=$id'\"/>";
    $output.="<br/>";
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: i also have to use id of input boxes

Comment: That is in the code check - delete.php?id=$id. Try this it will work

Comment: $sql="delete from contacts where id=".$_POST['DELETE'];
if($conn)
{
 if($conn->query($sql))
 {
  echo"row deleted sucessfully";
 }
}

Comment: If you are sending the information from page request mean through URL, You have need to use by GET method. id=".$_GET['DELETE']. Check about GET and POST method. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post

Answer (score 0):

Replace with following code:

```
 echo"<input type='button' value='EDIT' onclick='document.location.href=\"/project1/edit.php";
 echo "?id=1\"'";
 echo" /><br>";
?>
```